# Testing a function with several side effects

Tags: unit-testing

Consider this (bash) function which has several side-effects (setting a global variable, printing to stdout):

```
describe() {
  printf '\n%s\n' "$1"

  skip_specs=false
}
```

It prints to `stdout` and sets the value of the global variable `skip_specs`.

What are the pros/cons of:

- one test per side-effect
- one test for both side-effects

Comment: The nice thing about asking yourself questions like this when writing tests is you begin to question whether what you did was the right thing in the first place. The question that should be asked here is _should_ this function have side effects at all? To answer your question more specifically though, in other languages I would expect to see one test with two assertions. If the question is unlocked, I'll move that to the answers, but it is opinion so it might not happen. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main pro's for one test per side-effect:

- Testing discrete functionality.
- If something brakes, you should immediately know from the broken test what it is you need to fix.

The main pro for on test for both side-effects is:

- Possibly less tests, so less code etc.

But if you goal is to determine how you should split the testing for the function, then I think you're asking the wrong question.  I would say that the real question is does your application view those two effects as a single unit.

Is it valid for the message to be written to the console, when the variable isn't set?  Is it valid for the variable to be set, when the message isn't written to the console?  If the answer to either of these questions is no, then you should be testing both effects together.  If it's yes, you should be testing them in isolation.

Note, that with either scenario, testing the behaviour may still result in multiple tests per effect.  So, even if both effects are being tested together, you may still end up with two or more tests.